# Auth.js authorize function logs an error when return null

Tags: next.js, credentials, next-auth

In Auth.js in Next.js in the Credentials Provider, the authorize function logs the error below when i return null from it even if i but the signIn function in try catch block.

The Error:

```
[auth][error] CredentialsSignin: Read more at https://errors.authjs.dev#credentialssignin
    at Module.callback (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@auth/core/lib/actions/callback/index.js:266:30)
    at async AuthInternal (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@auth/core/lib/index.js:67:24)
    at async Auth (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@auth/core/index.js:126:29)
    at async D:\Programming\Projects\FullStack\sociatech\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:63809
    at async eU.execute (D:\Programming\Projects\FullStack\sociatech\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:53964)
    at async eU.handle (D:\Programming\Projects\FullStack\sociatech\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:65062)
    at async doRender (D:\Programming\Projects\FullStack\sociatech\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1333:42)
    at async cacheEntry.responseCache.get.routeKind (D:\Programming\Projects\FullStack\sociatech\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1543:40)
    at async DevServer.renderToResponseWithComponentsImpl (D:\Programming\Projects\FullStack\sociatech\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1463:28)
    at async DevServer.renderPageComponent (D:\Programming\Projects\FullStack\sociatech\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1856:24)
    at async DevServer.renderToResponseImpl (D:\Programming\Projects\FullStack\sociatech\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1894:32)
    at async DevServer.pipeImpl (D:\Programming\Projects\FullStack\sociatech\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:911:25)  
    at async NextNodeServer.handleCatchallRenderRequest (D:\Programming\Projects\FullStack\sociatech\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:271:17)
    at async DevServer.handleRequestImpl (D:\Programming\Projects\FullStack\sociatech\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:807:17)
    at async D:\Programming\Projects\FullStack\sociatech\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:331:20
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (D:\Programming\Projects\FullStack\sociatech\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:151:20)
    at async DevServer.handleRequest (D:\Programming\Projects\FullStack\sociatech\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:328:24)
    at async invokeRender (D:\Programming\Projects\FullStack\sociatech\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:163:21)  
    at async handleRequest (D:\Programming\Projects\FullStack\sociatech\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:342:24) 
    at async requestHandlerImpl (D:\Programming\Projects\FullStack\sociatech\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:366:13)
    at async Server.requestListener (D:\Programming\Projects\FullStack\sociatech\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\start-server.js:140:13)
```

I searched for it in the official auth.js website and don't found an answer!